# Regex JS - Find exactly three dots

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to find exactly three dots after each other, not 4 not 2 only 3.

e.g.:

- Hello world...      (Matches)
- Hello World....     (Do not match)
- .. .                (Do not match)
- . . .               (Do not match)
- Hello World...Yes   (Matches)
- Hello World...[Linkebreak] (Matches)

First start was:

```
    return text.replace(/\.{3}/g, 'FOUND!');
```

but doesn't work really good. Any ideas?

Comment: You should create a capture group by encapsulating your search in brackets. `/(\.{3})/g`

Comment: Ah, the old lookbehind problem with JS.. Also `hello...world...what` has two sets of 3 dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
return text.replace(/(^|[^.])\.{3}(?!\.)/, '$1FOUND!');
```

This works like this:

- Store the 1st character if:

  - It is the beginning of the line
  - Isn't a dot
- Count 3 dots
- Check if the next one isn't a dot

  - This is called a `negative lookahead`

Since we use a greedy match on the first character, we have to add it to the replacement, therefore the `$1`.

---

If it is a requirement to replace every instance of those 3 dots, add the flag `g` at the end of the regex. Making it look like this:

```
/(^|[^.])\.{3}(?!\.)/g
```

The flag `g` indicates that it will perform a global matching, instead of matching a single time.

Comment: This will only replace the first instance of the `...`

Answer (score 4):

The Regex you want:

```
/(^|[^.])\.{3}([^.]|$)/g
```

The JS Replacement you want:

```
text.replace(/(^|[^.])\.{3}([^.]|$)/g, '$1FOUND!$2');
```

Here's the break down of the Regex:

- `(^|[^.])`: No characters `^` or `|` a character that's not a dot `[^.]`
- `\.{3}`: followed by three dots
- `([^.]|$)` followed by a character that's not a dot `[^.]` or `|` the end of the string `$`
- `$1`: Include first capture group
- `$2`: Include last capture group

The only downside of this method is that any combinations of `...` separated by a single character will be skipped, so you'll have to run the replacement twice:

```
... ... ... ... ...   ... => FOUND!!! ... FOUND!!! ... FOUND!!!   FOUND!!!
```

Test string:

```
"This should be found -> ... \
This should not be found -> .... \
Something will be found here -> .. .. ...... ... .. \
Multiple found -> ... ... .. ... ... .. \
... <- That's found \
Next line will be found \
..."
```

Output 1 iteration:

```
"This should be found -> FOUND!
This should not be found -> ....
Something will be found here -> .. .. ...... FOUND! ..
Multiple found -> FOUND! ... .. FOUND! ... ..
FOUND! <- That's found
Next line will be found
FOUND!"
```

Output 2 iterations:

```
"This should be found -> FOUND!
This should not be found -> ....
Something will be found here -> .. .. ...... FOUND! ..
Multiple found -> FOUND! FOUND! .. FOUND! FOUND! ..
FOUND! <- That's found
Next line will be found
FOUND!"
```

Comment: That breaks stuff. It will replace the first and last characters.

Comment: Didn't realize you were using this for find and replace. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
^[^.]*\.{3}[^.]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY3pC1/1)